# A little question on notation of integral

Tags: notation

On Wikipedia articles, I often see $$\frac{dx}{x}$$ where the $\frac{1}{x}$ can often be absorbed into powers of $x$ in the integrand.

For example, the Mellin transform is expressed as $$\int_0^\infty x^s f(x) \frac{dx}{x}$$ instead of $$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(x) \, dx.$$

What is the reason behind?

Comment: Oftentimes it just looks nicer. They mean the exact same thing.

Comment: If you want to get really deep into it, $\int f\,\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes (or Riemann-Stieltjes) integral corresponding to the map $x \mapsto \log(x)$.  But, unless you want to go deeper into the mathematical field of analysis, then you are probably safe regarding it as "just a notation."

Answer (score 1):

It is about the Haar measure on the multiplicative group $\left((0,\infty),\dfrac{dx}{x}\right)$. And when you are dealing with convolution in this group, one writes that $f\ast g(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}g(y^{-1}x)f(y)\dfrac{dy}{y}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I know very little about convolution and Haar measure.

Comment: What I wrote is the definition of Haar measure with respect the multiplicative group with respect to the measure $\dfrac{dx}{x}$. In general, you have something like $f\ast g(x)=\displaystyle\int_{X}g(y^{-1}x)f(y)d\mu(y)$.